# Hive Timestamp erroring as Binary

Tags: amazon-web-services, types, hive, amazon-emr

I'm trying to insert to a table with a query in an EMR cluster on AWS. The table is creating correctly, and a colleague can run the exact same code that I'm using and it won't fail. However, when I try to run the code, I get failures in Map1 that make the entire job fail with the error below for the query below.

Can someone help me figure out why my job is failing when I run it, but my friend can run it without issue? I've been staring at this for the entire day and can't get past it.

```sql
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      MODE        STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1            container       RUNNING     13          0        0       13      40       1  
Map 3 .......... container     SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0  
Map 5 .......... container     SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0  
Map 7 .......... container     SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0  
Map 8 .......... container     SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0  
Reducer 2        container        INITED      6          0        0        6       0       0  
Reducer 4 ...... container     SUCCEEDED      2          2        0        0       0       0  
Reducer 6 ...... container     SUCCEEDED      2          2        0        0       0       0  
Reducer 9 ...... container     SUCCEEDED      2          2        0        0       0       0  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 07/09  [========>>------------------] 34%   ELAPSED TIME: 132.71 s   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1544915203536_0453_2_07, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1544915203536_0453_2_07_000009, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1544915203536_0453_2_07_000009_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1840)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [VALUE] BINARY is not in the store: 
    at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the vectorization was the issue. These were the settings that would be activated at the beginning of the session.

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true;
```

By not activating this it was able to run slower but successfully. It seems hive does not like the timestamp value. At the bottom of the below wiki is a limitations piece. It definitely works without these options set.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Vectorized+Query+Execution

In summary, timestamps and vectorization don't like each other in hive.... But only sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

I think in the error :

> [tuning_event_start_ts] BINARY is not in the store

The most important point is : `not in the store`

Check your query (only the select without insert).

Wich table contains `TUNING_EVENT_START_TS` ?